# python Dictionary function call in class

Tags: python, class, oop, dictionary, python-2.x

I tried to implement my own stack in Python. When I choose any of 'pos', an error shows up

```
class Stack:
    '''This is Stack Class'''

    def __init__(self):
        self.stack=[]

    def push(self):
        '''Enter item to push into stack'''
        self.stack.append(raw_input("Enter item to stack: "))

    def pop(self):
        '''Pops item from stack'''
        if len(self.stack)==0:
            print 'Cannot pop from empty stack'
        else:        
            i = self.stack.pop(index=-1)
            print ('Item popped: [%s]'%i)

    def show(self):
        '''Display Stack Content'''
        print self.stack

    choiceDict={'p':push, 'o':pop, 's':show, 'q':quit}

def menu():
    '''This is a menu list for stack'''
    s=Stack()

    while True:
        while True:
            print '''Enter Choice
p) push
o) pop
s) show
q) quit'''
            c=raw_input('Enter choice > ').lstrip()[0].lower()
            if c not in 'posq':
                print '**Invalid Choice'
            else:
                break

        if(c=='q'):
            break
        s.choiceDict[c]()

if __name__=='__main__':
    menu()
```

Error:

> ```
> s.choiceDict[c]() TypeError: push() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
> ```

ps: If there are any other bugs in code. I'll be happy to know them :)

And by the way I just want the way to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The functions in `Stack.choiceDict[c]` are not bound to any instance, regardless of whether you access the class attribute `choiceDict` through the instance `s`. You will still have to provide an instance when calling the function:

```
s.choiceDict[c](s)
```

Or more revealingly:

```
Stack.choiceDict[c](s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `choiceDict` to the menu function and initialize as follows:

```
choice_dict = {'p': s.push, 'o': s.pop, 's': s.show, 'q': s.quit}
```

Then use it like:

```
choice_dict[c]()
```

This is because your `choiceDict` does not know anything about `s`, but all your methods requires `self` param:

```
In [14]: class Foo:
    ...:     def foo(self):
    ...:         print('foo is called')
    ...:     methods = {'foo': foo}
    ...:

In [15]: f = Foo()

In [16]: f.foo()
foo is called

In [17]: f.foo
Out[17]: <bound method Foo.foo of <__main__.Foo object at 0x111ec2048>>

In [18]: f.methods['foo']
Out[18]: <function __main__.Foo.foo>
```

Here you can see the difference between `f.methods['foo']` and `f.foo`. The first one is bound to `f`, the second one is just a function inside a class

```
In [19]: f.methods['foo']()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-a6f2f6e3b450> in <module>()
----> 1 f.methods['foo']()

TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Calling `foo` using `methods` dict raises the same error because the `self` parameter is missed.

```
In [20]: f.methods['foo'](f)
foo is called
```

Alternatively, you can pass `f` to the function - this will also work, but seems not quite right because you already using `f` in the expression. Though this is effectively the same as moving `choice_dict` to the `menu` function as I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

`push` belongs to each **instance** of your class. Therefore, you need your dispatching dictionary to call the method belonging to that instance via `self`.

I recommend you put this in `__init__` so that the dispatcher is defined when you initialise a new class instance:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.stack = []
    self.choiceDict = {'p': self.push, 'o': self.pop, 's': self.show, 'q': self.quit}
```

Comment: It feels rather unnecessary to provide each instance with its own `dict`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, I guess I tend to make these instance attributes in case they need to be overwritten for specific instances. You're right, I guess, if these are set in stone and shouldn't be overwritable.